# Basic webscraping-but I cannot solve this problem

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I want to practice webscrapping and follow some video. That video said that:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://comic.naver.com/webtoon/list?titleId=811721&tab=wed"
res = requests.get(url)
res.raise_for_status()  

soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")
cartoons = soup.find_all("p", attrs={"class":"EpisodeListList__title_area--fTivg"})
title = cartoons[0].span.get_text()
```

can extract "51화 : 막장동 드라마" from the following html text in the developer's tool page

```
<div class="EpisodeListList__info_area--Rq03U">
  <p class="EpisodeListList__title_area--fTivg">
    <span class="EpisodeListList__title--lfIzU">51화 : 막장동 드라마 (1)</span>
```

But, only

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\Users\SH Kim\Desktop\Python\Webscraping2\9_bs4_gauss.py", line 10, in <module>
        title = cartoons[0].span.get_text()
    IndexError: list index out of range
```

is returned...

When I asked to Chatgpt but it only advice me to use the script:

```
if cartoons:
    title = cartoons[0].get_text(strip=True)
    print(title)
else:
    print("No matching elements found.")
```

Yes, This script works and returns `No matching elements found.` but it cannot solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Content of website is generated dynamically via JavaScript, so you have to use the XHR / API request pulling the information as JSON.

An alternative would be to use `selenium` or any other package that mimics browser behaviour and render the dynamic parts.

###### Example

```
import requests

url = 'https://comic.naver.com/api/article/list?titleId=811721&page=1'

data = requests.get(url).json()

for article in data['articleList']:
    print(article.get('subtitle'))
```

---

```
51화 : 막장동 드라마 (1)
50화 : 쓰레기 팔기 (2)
49화 : 쓰레기 팔기 (1)
48화 : 여름이 싫어
47화 : 결심(4)
46화 : 결심(3)
45화 : 결심(2)
44화 : 결심(1)
43화 : 빨래하기
42화 : 노동의 맛 (2)
41화 : 노동의 맛 (1)
40화 : 비닐봉지 (5)
39화 : 비닐봉지 (4)
38화 : 비닐봉지 (3)
37화 : 비닐봉지 (2)
36화 : 비닐봉지 (1)
35화 : 오들오들 계백순
34화 : 옷을 사자
33화 : 공포의 편의점 (2)
32화 : 공포의 편의점 (1)
```

Comment: So I need to expand my understanding to API...I got it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think `lxml` might have a problem with the code of the page here. You can try to switch to a pure html parser like this. It seems to work for you html sniplet at least:

```
html = """<div class="EpisodeListList__info_area--Rq03U">
  <p class="EpisodeListList__title_area--fTivg">
    <span class="EpisodeListList__title--lfIzU">51화 : 막장동 드라마 (1)"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
cartoons = soup.find_all("p", attrs={"class":"EpisodeListList__title_area--fTivg"})
title = cartoons[0].span.get_text()
print(title)
```

This outputs '51화 : 막장동 드라마 (1)'.

To make this work in your original code, you would need to change this line as follows:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
```

If that doesn't work with the whole html fetched from the site, then it is most likely because there is no tag like `<p class="EpisodeListList__title_area--fTivg"` in the result. You could check that by looking at the html source of the page. It is possible that the suffix `fTivg` is not static for some reason. If so, you can try using a regex to match the class.

Comment: I think that '<p class="EpisodeListList__title_area--fTivg"' might make a problem. I will try to understand the problem by focusing it. Thank you for detailed advice!

Comment: If you think the class is not a static string (e.g. generated), then just pass a regexp. E.g. something like
`attrs={"class": re.compile("EpisodeListList__title_area.*"})` (don't forget to `import re` on top of your script for that).